# How do I add an agument that has spaces in it, in a Bach script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, arguments

I am creating a script to check if my Minecraft server is running or not, but My script never works.
Note: I'm not that good at Bach script coding
I am using Win 10 Pro

I've looked online and found this

```
echo %~1
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Cave SMP Vanilla 1.19.3" /FO CSV > search.log
FINDSTR Cave SMP Vanilla 1.19.3 search.log > found.log
FOR /F %%A IN (found.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

echo server off

:end

echo server on

del search.log
del found.log
pause
```

but it just outputs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F87z.png)
(The server is currently running)
I expect it to output `server is on`

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks Alot!!!!!

Comment: You do not have an executable process on your system named `Cave SMP Vanilla 1.19.3`. Most executable processes usually carry an `.exe` extension. I would advise that you open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr.exe /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. It should show you how the `findstr.exe` command utility works, and could be used for your required purpose. When you've done that, before you close the window, type `tasklist /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out all about using `tasklist.exe` command utility. Frankly you need to make more effort, not just expect someone else to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.
There is `notepad.exe` as Image Name instead of your `Cave SMP Vanilla 1.19.3`. You can try to replace `notepad.exe` and check if it works for you.

```
@echo OFF

TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FO CSV > search.log
FINDSTR /R /C:"notepad.exe" search.log > found.log
FOR /F %%A IN (found.log) DO ( 
    IF %%~zA EQU 0 ( 
    GOTO :end ) 
)

echo server off
GOTO :end_file

:end
echo server on

:end_file

del search.log
del found.log
pause
```

Comment: Thank you, I read the other guys comment and remembered the because I'm using java to run the server, I can just look for java.exe, but thank you so much!!!